# Invalid context 0x0 error when calling UIGraphicsBeginImageContext. Similar error occurs when calling any Core Graphics 'AddPath' functions as well

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-graphics

The error occurs right on this line:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 6, height: 6))
```

It is from within a custom class as seen here:

```
import UIKit

class bulletGroup: UIControl {

  var radius: CGFloat = 3
  var bulletSpacing: CGFloat = 10
  var numberOfBullets = 5
  var bulletColor = UIColor.blackColor()

  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapButt)

    bulletColor.set()

    for i in 1...numberOfBullets{
      CGContextAddArc(ctx, CGFloat(Float(i) * Float(bulletSpacing)), self.frame.size.height/2, radius, 0, CGFloat(2 * M_PI), 0)
      CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke)
    }
  }

  func fillCircle(circleNUmber: Int){
    bulletColor.set()

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 6, height: 6))
  }
}
```

I'm extremely new to Core Graphic. Is there something wrong with creating a context outside of the drawRect function when subclassing UIControl?

EDIT: The exact error is:

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Comment: I had this before myself. Did not know how to fix so I ended up re-factoring all my code :/ If there is a solution Im all ears

Comment: As LastMove says, if you want to redraw the view having changed some property, you should call `setNeedsDisplay`. BTW, if you _were_ going to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` (for example, you were going to use CoreGraphics to create an image that would be used later), it must be balanced with a call to `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is common.
Some people just ignore it.
It mean that you are calling CG functions without Context.
CG is a C API not object oriented So you need to provide a Context each time.
If you are in a `drawRect:` method, it is not needed.
So in your fillCircle you have to provide a valid context.
The problem is that when you do `bulletColor.set()` there is no context.

In your case the best think to do is to force a call of the `drawrect:` method.
for that you can call this method in the fillCircle function.

```
self.setNeedsDisplay();
```

for that you have to handle all of your drawing logic in the drawRect method.

**Apple made a Core Graphics guide:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html
It is very interesting.

**note**:Quartz 2d is Core Graphics.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your response, I have another query however. I'm trying to create a custom control, does this mean I cannot have a separate function called `fillCircle`? If everything is done in drawRect how can I fill in a specific circle?

Comment: If the circle is part of your "bulletGroup" drawing. you could create a variable in that class and set it in the fillCircle method.
What do you want to fill within fillCircle?

Comment: I'm just trying to fill in the bullets with black. I originally wanted to do this in a separate function, but I learned that I can only successfully use the `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` from within drawRect. Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a simpler way to fill in the circles?

Comment: So you will call fillCircle from the drawRect method?

Comment: if yes it seems ok but remove     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 6, height: 6))

Comment: Ignoring common problems is not now real men do it.

Answer (score 1):

See this SO [CGContextSaveGState invalid context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377299/cgcontextsavegstate-invalid-context) that helped me to resolve this issue after unsuccessfully fiddling with status bar appearance keys. It might mean your image has just size of (0,0).

Comment: This was exactly the reason why I got this error.  Good call.